# How to print id card with html php js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, photoshop

i'm making a web app with a users crud, when i create a new user, i need print a PVC id card with the recent create user data (like a report).

I need a practical way to do this, this can be do with a pluggin? or need download a desktop app and connect this with my mysql db.

PD: We have a epson printer and a zebra printer.

Thx !

Answer (score 2):

I made a jsfidle here for example [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/8cqkez5a/)

```
function nWin() {
 var w = window.open();
 var html = $("#toNewWindow").html();

 $(w.document.body).html(html);
 w.print();
}

 $(function() {
 $("a#print").click(nWin);
});
```

you can just add some php variable to the #toNewWindow